# scoring for mlp regressor for pipelines

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm struggling to figure out what `cross_val_score` and pipeline.score returns when using `MLPRegressor`. I was under the impression that it returned `r2` score, however when i run `sklearn.metrics.r2_score` with the data I receive a completely different value.
eg here is my code.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=i)
scaler=StandardScaler()
x_train=scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test=scaler.transform(x_test)


mlp=MLPRegressor(activation='relu', solver='lbfgs', hidden_layer_sizes=(6,6,6), max_iter=10000, learning_rate_init=0.001)
pipeline=Pipeline([('transformer',scaler),('estimator',mlp)])
pipeline.fit(x,y)
cv=KFold(n_splits=3)
scorescrossval=cross_val_score(pipeline,x_test,y_test,cv=cv)
print('scores cross val',scorescrossval)
print('accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)'%(scorescrossval.mean(),scorescrossval.std()*2))
print('pipeline score',pipeline.score(x_test,y_test))

mlp.fit(x_train,y_train)
predictions=mlp.predict(x_test)
RTWO=sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_test,predictions)
```

which gives,

```
scores cross val [0.97435245 0.96969591 0.98333161]
accuracy: 0.98 (+/- 0.01)
pipeline score -0.7028296099215846
RTWO -5.735668230366273
```

I'm struggling to know which value to trust, and determine what they mean. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

These scores are not comparable because each time a different data is used for learning the model.

Let's break your code in three parts:

1)

```
pipeline.fit(x,y)
print('pipeline score',pipeline.score(x_test,y_test))
```

2)

```
cv=KFold(n_splits=3)
scorescrossval=cross_val_score(pipeline,x_test,y_test,cv=cv)
print('scores cross val',scorescrossval)
print('accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)'%(scorescrossval.mean(),scorescrossval.std()*2))
```

3)

```
mlp.fit(x_train,y_train)
predictions=mlp.predict(x_test)
RTWO=sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_test,predictions)
```

Code 3 is easily separated.

One thing that IMO you are misunderstanding about the `cross_val_score`
is that it only is testing and not learning from the data, but its not the case.

`cross_val_score` will split the supplied data according to the supplied `cv` and train the model those many number of times and report score on the remaining data. So your `x_test` and `y_test` will be split into 3 folds and each fold will be tested once based on learning of other folds. So you will get 3 scores.

Also, For code 1 and 2, I can change the order as I did above because `cross_val_score` will use a clone of `pipeline` object to learn on the data and report the scores. So your original `pipeline` is untouched.

Now can you understand the reason behind those different scores?

**Update for comment**:

In the code 1, you fit the pipeline on whole unscaled data and then test on the scaled part of same data. So the score should be somewhat higher. But you are getting -0.7028.

That's because, `x_test` is part of `x`, but scaled already and `pipe.score` will scale it again which is wrong.

Code 2 is the close to correct. But its only using 0.2 percent of your data and that too already scaled out of the `cross_val_score` which leads to data leakage. So the scores are high.

Code 3 also seems correct. In this case, the `RTWO` should match the output from `mlp.score(x_test, y_test)`. Now why its so low is another question. Whats the score on `(x_train, y_train)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand how different data is used and how the data is split for cross_val_score, however i dont understand why they are so different. accuracy from cross_val gives 0.98 which suggests a very good model, but r2_score gives -5, suggesting a terrible model. How do i know how to score the model? thank you

Comment: thank you your comment has helped massively. The score on `mlp.score(x_train, y_train)` is 0.992, which is dramatically different to the the score on `sklearn.metrics.r2_score(x_train, y_train)` at -899978!!!